# How to use SignalR under subdomain of Asp.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, subdomain, iis-6

I am working on a project which has subdomains like:

'example.com', 'app.example.com' and 'admin.example.com'

and iis is acting like each subdomain is like an app.
[iis snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V1sx.png)

I want to use SignalR under the sub domain 'app' but could not achieve. Installed the packages:

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.2.0-*"

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "0.2.0-*"

It worked under 'example.com' but not under 'app.example.com'

Got 404 error while trying to find the src 'signalr/hubs'.

How can I route the signalr to my subdomain 'app'.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.2.0-*" is dead. Don't use it. SignalR for Asp.NET Core version is developed [here](http://github.com/aspnet/SignalR). It's very early though and things keep changing rapidly.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have to wait then:)